# Mail app: switch-off auto-synchronisation of some accounts

Tags: macos, mail.app

I have multiple email accounts that I have configured in the mail app. Is is possible to turn the synchronisation off selectively for one or two accounts?

Comment: On macOS or iOS?

Comment: on macOS (need to fill chars..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... after looking over and over again, there is a solution. Right-click on the account and then click "take account offline"